# Indefinite vs definite Integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Strangely, *Mathematica* cannot do this definite integral:

```
Integrate[x/(x^2 + L^2)^(3/2), {x, 0, a}],
```

while for the indefinite one:

```
Integrate[x/(x^2 + L^2)^(3/2), x]
```

the software easily finds the solution:

```
-(1/Sqrt[L^2+x^2])
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably that's because Mathematica doesn't know what a is, it may be a complex number for example.

If you change your code to:

```
Integrate[x/(x^2 + L^2)^(3/2), {x, 0, a},Assumptions -> a \[Element] Reals]
```

you get a solution:

```
ConditionalExpression[(-1 + Sqrt[1 + a^2/L^2])/(
 Sqrt[1 + a^2/L^2] Sqrt[L^2]), 
 a >= 0 && (Re[L^2/a^2] >= 0 || Re[L^2/a^2] <= -1 || 
    L^2/a^2 \[NotElement] Reals) && Re[L^2] > 0]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. And if a and L are real and both >0? Can I impose these assumptions?

Comment: sure you can: Integrate[x/(x^2 + L^2)^(3/2), {x, 0, a}, 
 Assumptions -> {a > 0, L > 0}]